# Symfony3 send AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I want to send two variables ***id*** and ***commentary*** through an ***AJAX POST*** request.
The problem is that I don't get the POST variable but the route is reached.

JS:

```
$.post(Routing.generate('ajax_savecommentary', { id:id, commentary:commentary }), 
function(response)
{
}, "json");
```

Symfony:

```
public function saveCommentaryAction()
{
    if (!$this->get('session')->get('compte'))
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));

    $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
    $isAjax = $request->isXMLHttpRequest();

    if ($isAjax)
    {
        $information = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Information')->find($_POST['id']);

        $information->setCommentaire(str_replace('\n', '\\n', $_POST['commentary']));
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true, 'commentary' => $_POST['commentary']);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }
    $response = array("code" => 0, "success" => false);
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
}
```

The error:

> http://localhost/MyProject/web/app_dev.php/ajax/save/commentary/?id=61&commentary=MyCommentary.
>
> ```
> {"code":0,"success":false}
> ```

More Symfony error:

```
GET Parameters

Key/Value

commentary/MyCommentary

id/61
```

And the routing is case needed:

```
ajax_savecommentary:
    defaults: { _controller: CommonBundle:Default:saveCommentary }
    path:     /ajax/save/commentary/
    options:
        expose: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the request passed to the Controller Action instead of retrieve it from the container. So try this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

public function saveCommentaryAction(Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->get('session')->get('compte'))
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));

    $isAjax = $request->isXMLHttpRequest();
```

instead of this:

```
public function saveCommentaryAction()
{
    if (!$this->get('session')->get('compte'))
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('accueil'));

    $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
    $isAjax = $request->isXMLHttpRequest();
```

**UPDATE:**

You can restrict your routing with [Customized Route Matching with Conditions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#completely-customized-route-matching-with-conditions), as example on your case as follow:

```
ajax_savecommentary:
    defaults: { _controller: CommonBundle:Default:saveCommentary }
    path:     /ajax/save/commentary/
    options:
        expose: true
    condition: "request.isXmlHttpRequest()"
    methods:  [POST]
```

**UPDATE:**

There is a typo in the routing generation in the JS side:

```
$.post(Routing.generate('ajax_savecommentary', { id:id, commentary:commentary }), 
function(response)
{
}, "json");
```

you pass the data as argument of the routing.generate function so it concatenate the params as query string. so try this:

```
$.post(Routing.generate('ajax_savecommentary'), { id:id, commentary:commentary }, 
function(response)
{
}, "json");
```

Another advice is about to use the $request object for obtain the data instead of the superglobal PHP attribute, so use:

```
$request->request-get('commentary');
```

instead of:

```
 $_POST['commentary']
```

More info [here in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony).

Hope this help

Comment: Well it worked about the isAjax condition. But I still can't access the $_POST variables.
Actually I found out they're sent as Get variable and not post, and if I look at $_GET['id'] it works. For me it still not fixed.

Comment: Hi @ValentinBEAULE sorry i didn't see how do you access to the request data. In symfony is preferred to use [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony) approach so don't use the superglobal variables.

Comment: @ValentinBEAULE you generate a wrong route and put the data in the route instead o passing as third arguments to the jquery post function

Comment: Thanks for your methode, I'll use it for now. About the route, how is it wrong? I do access to the function. Have you an example? Don't hesitate to post an answer as you almost already resolved the problem.